# Django app error

Tags: python, django, linux, error-handling

I've made a simple leads-collecting app in Python, under Ubuntu 10.10, using Django as framework and mysql as database and it works perfectly fine. Well, almost perfectly because once in a while it throws some malicious server error when trying to save a new lead. This is my error email:

```
[Django] Error (EXTERNAL IP): /myapp/save-lead/
...
IOError: request data read error
...
'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
'REQUEST_URI': '/myapp/save-lead/',
'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/var/www/my_domain_name/myapp/app/app_name.wsgi',
```

The app already holds 10 000 leads at the moment, but I've received this error 3 times now. Where is the problem?

Comment: are you saving to a file rather than a database? or reading from a file? looks like two IO processes conflict with each other.

Comment: @Uko: I don't believe so. The exception states, that was a IOError reading from the request. My guess is, that this happens if the request that contains the POST is incomplete. I.e. the user hits 'cancel' or his internet connection disconnects. The problem here is  not the exception but that the application needs to handle this situation gracefully. 
user823148: Is the POST data large?

Comment: @Martin Thurau: the POST is not large, I'm just catching some simple fields, name, surname,e-mail, phone nr, ipaddr, stamp.

Comment: @Uku Loskit: I'm saving to a mysql database and I am not reading from a file.

Comment: If it happened 3 times out of 10 000, you're not realistically going to improve the reliability. Just have the app retry on failure.

Comment: It's most likely a web server glitch, prematurely terminated connection or something like that. You can double check front server config, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.